# Disadvantages of calling realloc in a loop

Tags: c, memory-management, out-of-memory, realloc

I'm trying to implement some math algorithms in `C` on Windows 7, and I need to repeatedly increase size of my array.

Sometimes it fails because `realloc` can't allocate memory.
But if I allocate a lot of memory at once in the beginning it works fine.

Is it a problem with the memory manager? Can anyone explain me this please?

Comment: Why don't you use stl containers? `std::vector` or `std::dequeue` for example? Or is `C++` tag accidental.

Comment: Well, say you have an array that is 500MB big and you want to grow it by 100MB. You need 1100MB to do that, since first a new array of 600MB is created, data is copied to the new array and then the old array is freed up. While allocating a 600MB array in the first place only needs 600MB. So you have a bigger chance to run out of memory or address space with realloc.

Comment: If you can calculate how much space you need in advance then preallocating is faster anyway (this applies to STL containers too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you allocate/deallocate memory many times, it may create fragmentation in the memory and you may not get big contiguous chunk of the memory.
2. When you do a realloc, some extra memory **may** be needed for a short period of time to move the data.

If your algorithm does not need contiguous memory or can be changed to work on non-contiguous memory, consider using linked-lists of array (Something link std::dequeue of C++) that will avoid copying of data and your code may not suffer OOM. If you know the worst case memory requirement for the array, it is better to keep that memory allocated from the beginning itself, as it will avoid the cost of allocation and data moving when compared with `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

I you want your algorithms to work fast, try to do all the memory allocation up front. Memory allocation is an unbounded operation and will kill your performance. So speculate a reasonable worst case and allocate enough for that. If you do need to realloc later fine but don't do so continuously.