# How do i pass values in an empty vector?

Tags: c

how do i pass values into an empty vector (factors) using a for loop ?

in this code I'm trying to find the numbers of factors of a number and then pass the factors into an empty vector but it keeps giving me zeroes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

    int facVar = 57;
    int S;
    double numFact = 0;
    int k;
    int factors1[4];

    for (S = 1; S <= facVar; S = S + 1)
    {
        if (facVar % S == 0)
        {
            numFact = numFact + 1;

        }
    }
    int factNum = numFact;
    int factors[factNum];
    int indices[factNum];
    int i;
    printf("the number of factors is  %.lf \n", numFact);

    for (k = 0; k < factNum; k++)
    {

        factors[k] = S;
    }

    for (k = 0; k < factNum; k++)
    {
        printf("factors are %.lf", factors[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `"%d"` to print integers, read the documentation.

Comment: You are filling the array(factors) with the same value (S = 58) in all the elements of your array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to call :

```
#include <math.h>
```

After that in the first loop you check the factor of your number you don't store it in an array:

```
for(S=1 ; S <= facVar ; S = S + 1){
if(facVar % S == 0){
    numFact = numFact + 1;

}
}
```

So you need to store the factors in the array factors.
This program help you to get the results that you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

int facVar = 57;
int S, k;
int numFact = 0;

for(S = 1, k = 0 ; S <= facVar ; S++){
    if(facVar % S == 0){
      numFact++;

    }
}
int factors[numFact];
for(S = 1, k = 0 ; S <= facVar ; S++){
    if(facVar % S == 0){
      factors[k] = S;
      k++;

    }
}
printf("the number of factors is:  %d \n" , numFact);

for(k = 0; k < numFact ; k++){
    printf("factors are: %d\n" , factors[k]);
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Calling realloc in a loop like this is a bad idea, since it is very inefficient. It would be much faster to pre-calculate the needed size, as in the original post.

Comment: @Lundin if we will follow the original post we will use the loop twice.The first to get the number of factors and the second to fill the factors array.Because in the original post he declared the array after the loop.

Comment: Concerning **realloc** I found this [Disadvantages of calling realloc in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976295/disadvantages-of-calling-realloc-in-a-loop?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: The concern was indeed about using realloc in a loop, not about doing the same loop twice, which is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, your program just needs a bit of clean-up. Get rid of float numbers, superfluous variables etc. Also to count the number of factors and calculating them is the same algorithm, repeated twice. `factors[k] = S;` didn't make any sense.

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  const int facVar = 57;
  int numFact = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= facVar; i++)
  {
    if (facVar % i == 0)
    {
      numFact++;
    }
  }
  printf("The number of factors is  %d \n", numFact);

  int factors[numFact];
  int fact_n=0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= facVar; i++)
  {
    if (facVar % i == 0)
    {
      factors[fact_n] = i;
      fact_n++;
    }
  }

  printf("The factors are: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < numFact; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", factors[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```